# React native list of buttons

Tags: list, button, react-native

I am making a react native app which includes a list of buttons on each page, at the moment I am using scrollview which is populated by touchable highlight but the buttons are really slow.  is there a better way to do this?

Edit:  All the buttons take the user along a navigatorIOS, could that be the cause of them being so slow?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'slow'? Give us some codes

Comment: here is an example page

Comment: Where... I've not seen it..

Comment: sorry it didnt load due to being too big trying to make a plan :p

Comment: Are you logging a bunch of stuff out? That can sometimes slow down the perf.